# Running consol application in debug mode with WCF selfhosting?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, self-hosting

I have a WCF service hosted in a consol application(that also acts as the Windows Service installer), pleas see more here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

This is how the class in the consol application looks like :

```
public class MyAppWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost _MyAppClientServiceHost = null;
        public ServiceHost _MyAppIntegrationServiceHost = null;
        public ServiceHost _MyAppserviceHost = null;

        public MyAppWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "MyApp Service";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new MyAppWindowsService());
        }

        private void StopService(ServiceHost serviceHost)
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                  serviceHost.Close();
                  serviceHost = null;
            }
        }
        private ServiceHost StartService(Type serviceType)
        {
            ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
            // provide the base address.
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType);

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            serviceHost.Open();

            return serviceHost;
        }
        private void StartServices()
        {
            StopService(_MyAppClientServiceHost);
            StopService(_MyAppIntegrationServiceHost);
            StopService(_MyAppServiceHost);

            _MyAppClientServiceHost = StartService(typeof(MyApp.ServiceImplementation.MyAppClientService));
            _MyAppIntegrationServiceHost = StartService(typeof(MyApp.ServiceImplementation.MyAppIntegration));
            _MyAppServiceHost = StartService(typeof(MyApp.ServiceImplementation.HL7Service));
        }
        private void StopServices()
        {
            StopService(_MyAppClientServiceHost);
            StopService(_MyAppIntegrationServiceHost);
            StopService(_MyAppHl7ServiceHost);
        }

        // Start the Windows service.
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            StartServices();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            StopServices();
        }

    }
```

This is made for running in a Windows Service, how do I make so I can run this as a regular selfhost in debug mode(during development)? or do I really have to start a special project to be able to debug this servuce during runtime?

**Edit:**

I decided to use the existing windows service project but change the main to something like this :

```
public static void Main()
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--- MyApp Services ---");
                Console.WriteLine("Starting services...");
                Instance.StartServices();
                Console.WriteLine("--Finished--");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Instance.StopServices();
            }
            else
                ServiceBase.Run(new MyAppWindowsService());
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I do

**Solution A**

- Install a Windows Service using `InstallUtil` from my *Debug\bin* folder
- Stop and start service using `sc start` or `sc stop`
- Once service started do *Debug > Attach to Process...* and attach VS to the service

**Solution B**

Have a [Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) call on the first line of the [OnStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) method.

**Solution C**

Add a temp separate console application that does the same job as your service.

Comment: When the service was running in II7 I could just state that the Website host should be started when in debug and that it was to be runned from localhost. This was a great solution. But now, say that I already have my WCF service installed as a windows service and then starts my consol application for debugging, this consol app will try to start a WCF service on the same channel that is already used by the Windows service? This means that I have to stop the Windows Service before debugging my consol App(selfhost)? It would be great if I could just hit debug in visual studio and nothing more.

Comment: @SnowJim I see you point and I totally agree it is a pain. But so far this is what I came up with. I am not aware of any simpler solution. I would work with option C (client and server are two console applications and you can configure to start them both on F5). Once you don't need to debug it much I would switch for option A or B.

Comment: Thanks! My solution is to use the existing project but instead of ServiceBase.Run(new(MyAppWindowsService() in the main I added a check for Dubugger.IsAttached and if so manually start the services and also show some info in the consol. This works great so far.

Comment: I usually use a command-line argument for this. If the program is started with a "/standalone" arg, start as an application. Otherwise, start as a service.